# Converting app.js from create-react-app to react native, getting error Invariant Violation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I had previously created my project using create-react-app, and decided to use react native in order to get it published.  I started a new project using react native, then copied in my app.js file.
Now I'm getting this error:

```
Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.
```

[image: Invariant Violation]

I'm not sure what this means.  For example, lines 158-167:

```
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="diceAlias">
          <Form.Label>Alias</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Description of Roll" onChange={handleDiceAliasInput} />
          <Form.Text className="text-muted">
            Description of Roll
          </Form.Text>
        </Form.Group>
```

Comment: The reference to line 158 is simply the container for which the error happened. To help, if you post the rest of the code within that block, such as line 162 where the error likely is, we can assist you further.

Comment: Added additional lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

In react native the error

> Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a 
>   component.

is common when you try to do something like this:

```
    return (
        {this.state.showText && <Text>I am showing text.</Text>}
    )
```

To resolve your error find the code block where the error is coming from and change it to a ternary operator.  So the example above would become:

```
    return (
        {this.state.showText ? <Text>I am showing text.</Text> : null}
    )
```

Without seeing your code I cannot be certain this is causing the error but it is likely.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting the additional code.

```
<Form.Text className="text-muted">
   Description of Roll
</Form.Text>
```

With the more recent React Native, all text you want to display must be nested within a React Native `<Text>Text goes here</Text>` wrapper.

Simply import Text from 'react-native' with your other react native imports and update your code to

```
<Form.Text className="text-muted">
  <Text>Description of Roll</Text>
</Form.Text>
```

And you should resolve this issue.